# Populate spiderplot from data file in gnuplot 5.4

Tags: gnuplot

The recent release of gnuplot 5.4 came out with a lot of neat new features, to include the use of "spiderplots" (sometimes also called radar plots, etc.).  Following [their demos](http://gnuplot.sourceforge.net/demo_5.4/spiderplot.html), I've been able to successfully plot a spiderplot using local data defined in the script.  However, I can't seem to figure out how to do it using a data file (e.g. *.csv).  I'd really like to do one similar to the last one on the demo list (multiple data series, markers, shading, etc.), but can't figure out the syntax on how to use the data from the file.

For something to work with, I've copied the array data from [that last example script](http://gnuplot.sourceforge.net/demo_5.4/spiderplot.7.gnu) and converted it into a *.csv format.  Feel free to use that as an example input file.  Thank you for any/all help!

```
Array1,Array2
15,25
75,25
20,50
43,50
90,75
50,50
```

Comment: And what exactly doesn't work? Maybe you're missing a `set datafile separator comma`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have the data file 'test.csv', the following script can be used to reproduce the last plot in demo.

```
set size ratio 1 1,1

# set title "To plot from 2 different files or arrays, use 'newspiderplot'"
set datafile separator comma

set spiderplot
set style spiderplot fs transparent solid 0.2 border lw 1 pt 6 ps 2
set for [i=1:6] paxis i range [0:100]
set paxis 1 tics font ',9'
set for [i=2:6] paxis i tics format ""
set grid spider lt black lc "grey" lw 0.5 back

set style data spiderplot
plot \
     keyentry with spiderplot lc 3 lw 3 title "Array #1", \
     for [i=1:6] "test.csv" every ::i::i using 1 lc 3 lw 3 title sprintf("Scale %d",i), \
     newspiderplot, \
     keyentry with spiderplot lc 4 lw 2 title "Array #2", \
     for [j=1:6] "test.csv" every ::j::j using 2 lc 4 lw 2 notitle
```

You have 2 series of 6 axis data. The loop body of the following code picks one value of row-number i and column-number 1 from "test.csv", which is same value in original code using 'Array1[i]'.

**This code**

```
     for [i=1:6] "test.csv" every ::i::i using 1 lc 3 lw 3 title sprintf("Scale %d",i), \
```

**Original code**

```
     for [i=1:|Array1|] Array1 using (Array1[i]) lc 3 lw 3 title sprintf("Scale %d",i), \
```

FYI, `|Array1|` is the expression which means the number of elements in `Array1`.

Comment: This was a perfect response, thank you!!  I caught the |Array1| meaning, but I appreciate the explanation.  I was mostly struggling how to insert the "test.csv" part into the plot line and point out how to access it.  I haven't used for loops in gnuplot much.  Thanks again!